# addEventListener's function doesn't check for both cases

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I'm doing a little daily project for a web developer course.

I'm having the user input his email as `fake.email@gmail.com` in an input tag, establish an array with the only permitted email being `["fake.email@gmail.com"]`, then I'll check `if (email != permittedEmail)` or `else if (email = permittedEmail)` and then print in console `"You can't use that email to register"` for the first case and `"That's good"` for the second case.

However, the event listener never finds the input email equal to `"fake.email@gmail.com"`.

```js
const input = document.getElementById("InputEmail");
const email = input.innerHTML;
const permittedEmail = ["fake.email@gmail.com"];
const buttonClick = document.getElementById("submit-button");

buttonClick.addEventListener('click', function () {
  if (email != permittedEmail) {
    console.log("You can't use that email to register");
  } else if (email = permittedEmail) {
    console.log("That's good");
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iecdLmaskl7CVkqkXNQ/ZH/XLlvWZOJyj7Yy7tcenmpD1ypASozpmT/E0iPtmFIB46ZmdtAc9eNBvH0H/ZpiBw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" /> </head> <div class="container py-5">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-6">
          <form>
              <h1 class="mb-5 fw-bold fs-1 text-center">Inserisci la tua mail</h1>
              <div class="mb-3">
                  <label for="InputEmail1" class="form-label">Indirizzo Email</label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="InputEmail" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
              </div>
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                  <div id="submit-button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</div>
              </div>
          </form>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm really new to JS so it could some typos or some basic logic mistakes but I can't really progress at this point so any help would be awesome!

Comment: = means set the value. == means compare the values. In if else if statements you will want to use == (or ===) but never a single = sign

Comment: `email = permittedEmail` is assigning the `permittedEmail` to the `email`. It is not making a check if they are equal. Use `==`.

Comment: @imvain2 I've just tried but it doesn't seem to work either...

Comment: @Pyrux you have multiple issues. David went through them.

Comment: Hi Pyrux! Welcome to SO! I see at least a couple of issues, there first one as somebody already mention is wrong operators for comparison. The second is that you are comparing a string (your form input) with an array of permittedEmails. This will never work as you would expect. Check [Array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes), instead. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are *several* problems here...

1. Use `.value` to get the value of an `<input>`, not `.innerHTML`
2. Don't get the value *when the page loads*, because the user hasn't typed anything yet.  Get the value in the `click` event handler.
3. This will always be true: `email != permittedEmail`  Because a single value and an array of values are never the same thing.  You probably want to use `.includes()` to check if an array includes a value.
4. This is assignment, not comparison: `email = permittedEmail`
5. You don't need the second `if` at all, since the logical condition is "all other cases" which is exactly what `else` means.

Putting all of those together...

```js
const input = document.getElementById("InputEmail");
const permittedEmail = ["fake.email@gmail.com"];
const buttonClick = document.getElementById("submit-button");

buttonClick.addEventListener('click', function () {
  const email = input.value;
  if (!permittedEmail.includes(email)) {
    console.log("You can't use that email to register");
  } else {
    console.log("That's good");
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iecdLmaskl7CVkqkXNQ/ZH/XLlvWZOJyj7Yy7tcenmpD1ypASozpmT/E0iPtmFIB46ZmdtAc9eNBvH0H/ZpiBw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" /> </head> <div class="container py-5">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-6">
          <form>
              <h1 class="mb-5 fw-bold fs-1 text-center">Inserisci la tua mail</h1>
              <div class="mb-3">
                  <label for="InputEmail1" class="form-label">Indirizzo Email</label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="InputEmail" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
              </div>
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                  <div id="submit-button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</div>
              </div>
          </form>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

As an aside... While not a logical problem, names are equally important.  This variable name is misleading:

```
const permittedEmail = ["fake.email@gmail.com"];
```

The name is *singular*, but the value is an array which is a *list* (plural) of values.  This misleading name led to this bug:

```
if (email != permittedEmail) {
```

Intuitively it makes sense to compare two singular things in this way.  But since one of these two things is not singular but is in fact plural, the comparison won't do what you expect it to do.  Because a basket of apples will never *itself* be an apple.

Use variable names which intuitively and semantically describe what they mean:

```
const permittedEmails = ["fake.email@gmail.com"];
```

Comment: Hey David, thank you so much for the reply. You clarified all my problems and thaught me some more, that was awesome!

In the end, I used your suggestions number 1, 2, 4 and 5 as you can see in the final repo: https://raw.githack.com/LorenzoPorrega/js-mail-dadi/main/mail.html .

I didn't implement suggestion number 3 given the fact that input the permittedEmail was giving the right alert but as of now, running the program with a unexpected email didn't produce the other alert. So, your suggestion of using includes must be implemented to create the right behaviour.

Thanks so much again!